# load Dicom images in google colab with python

Tags: python, file-upload

How can I enter a number of DICOM images at the same time into the google colab coding environment?

I can't load number of Dicom images with python

Answer (score 1):

After `mount`ing your Google Drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
My_Google_Drive = drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)
%cd '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks'
from google.colab import files
```

use `pydicom`'s `dcmread` function to load the file and then `matplotlib.pyplot`'s `imshow` to display the image:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
!pip install pydicom
import pydicom
file_name = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/DATA_FOLDERS/IMAGES/dicom_image1.dcm'
dicom_file = pydicom.dcmread(file_name)
plt.imshow(dicom_file.pixel_array, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

Outputs:

[image]